# Communication between 2 python GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess

In file 2, a value would be entered by the user and i want that value to be used in 1 file. Also i want to make a function to check file 2 that if file 2 is missing, file 1 should independently get a default value.
Would this also work if i convert the file into exe, I tried using os.path.exists("Path"), but i want it to be path independent, any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *


multiplier = Tk()
multiplier.config(background="BLACK")
multiplier.geometry("400x400")
multiplier.wm_title("Multiplier Selector")
label1 = Label(multiplier, text="Select the Appropriate Multiplier", bg="BLACK", fg="WHITE", font="Times 14 bold")
label1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1)
a = StringVar()
x2 = Radiobutton (multiplier, text="x2", font="Times 14 bold", bg="BLACK", fg="WHITE", value=1,command=lambda:a.set("2"),selectcolor="BLACK")
x4 = Radiobutton (multiplier, text="x4", font="times 14 bold", bg="BLACK", fg="WHITE", value=2, command=lambda:a.set("4"), selectcolor="BLACK")
x6 = Radiobutton (multiplier, text="x6", font="Times 14 bold", bg="BLACK", fg="WHITE", value=3, command=lambda:a.set("6"), selectcolor="BLACK")
button = Button (multiplier, text="value of a", fg="White", bg="BLACK", command=lambda:print (a.get()))
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
x2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3)
x4.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
x6.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.7)

multiplier.mainloop()
```

## file_2

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from file_3 import abc
def raise_frame(Frame):
  Frame.tkraise()

def on():
  if a2.get()=="" or a3.get()=="" or a4.get()=="" or a5.get()=="" or a6.get()=="" :
   messagebox.showerror("Error", "Empty Field")

 else:
    a = float(a1.get()) * 10000000000
    b = float(a2.get()) * 1000000000
    c = float(a3.get()) * 1000000
    d = float(a4.get()) * 1000
    e = float(a5.get())
    f = float(a6.get()) / 1000
    h = float(abc.get())
    g = float((a + b + c + d + e + f)/h)
     setframepowergreen.lift()
     print(g)
```

Comment: We can't have any idea without seeing your code, what is in file1 and file2?

Comment: This question is far too vague. Please edit your question to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: May be you can communicate between them through REST protocols. Extract the value from the user from file 1 and file 2 ,make call to the server from either of the GUI to the other one compare it and return the results .

Comment: Please share your code for better and effective help

Comment: i want to import the value of a in another python script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot provide much help because this question is very vague. From what I understand, however, is that you want to pass data from one file to another.

With classes, you can pass `self` as a parameter when you call a class/function from the second file. Then use that parameter to set a variable:

```
##### file_a.py #####
from file_b import B

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        b_object = B(self)
        print(self.varFromFileB)

A()

##### file_b.py #####
class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        var = 'this variable from file_b gets passed to file_a'
        a.varFromFileB = var
```

With functions, you can call a function/class from a second file and set a variable to its return value:

```
##### file_a.py #####
from file_b import B

def A():
    varFromFileB = B()
    print(varFromFileB)

A()

##### file_b.py #####
def B():
    var = 'this variable from file_b gets passed to file_a'
    return var
```

If your entire application is not too large, you can avoid those imports by keeping all of the code in one file. From there, you can use the 2 methods above, or put everything in 1 class/function to make things much easier.

Converting your application into an executable should not change anything. It will take care of all imports and dependencies for you.

Comment: I have written the same thing but it's showing syntax error @Nelson
    from 3 import a

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia A syntax error means you just typed something incorrectly. Post your code and I can help.

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia I still strongly suggest you post some code, but I can tell you right now that the error is because the filename starts with a number. Change the file's name to file_3 or something that starts with a character instead of a number

Comment: No. It doesn't matter what IDE you use, modules (files) should not start with numerals

Comment: It worked , thank you so much. That was really stupid of me.

Comment: I would convert file_3 into .exe, would it still work?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. Look into [pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial): both tools for converting Python apps to Windows executables. These tools convert your entire application into an executable, not just one script.

Comment: if you look at the program , you would see a button. I want value of a to be sent only when the button is pressed. Any idea how to do that

Comment: @VaibhavBhatia So when you click the button, it sends the selected value to whatever is in your other file? Just replace `lambda: print(a.get())` with `lambda: function_from_other_file(a.get())`. Again, seeing the code from the other file would help.

Comment: I have posted the code. The want the value to get imported only when the button in file_3 is clicked (The initial file)